# iPhone provisioning profile problem

Tags: iphone, deployment, certificate, provisioning

My iPhone application runs fine in the simulator.  I'm trying to deploy it onto a physical iPhone.  When I install the provisioning profile, my Organizer says "A signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain."

I can't resolve this.  What do I do?

Answer (score 8):

A) Did you create a provisioning profile in the iPhone development portal?

B) If so, does the name in the info.plist file match the appID you created in the portal and used to create that development profile (that is, if you had created an app id of "com.fredsgreatstuff.*" in the info.plist you'd replace "com.mycompany" with "com.fredsgreatstuff")

C) Did you set PRODUCT_NAME in the project settings for all targets (to something like "mygreatapp")

From the look of the error though you must have got the development cert wrong, or not downloaded the certificate from the portal generated after you uploaded your developer signing request.

The portal has pretty good instructions at this point (that didn't used to be the case), be very careful to follow every step to the letter.

Comment: I also followed all the steps.  But this is a mystery to me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've downloaded your certificate from the program portal. Double-click on it to create a private-public key pair in Keychain Access. The private key will be created when you download the cert and double-click on it.

If it does not, you might have to delete the certificate and create a new one. Make sure the in the certificate signing request you create, your name is exactly as you've mentioned in the portal.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a really good website with a checklist on troubleshooting code signing errors:
http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/05/how-to-fix-code-signing-errors/

Most of its content is covered by the posts above, but it is easier to work through.

FTR, I hit the same problem that Genericrich pointed out - my Development Profile didn't have the private key, but my Distribution one did.  As a workaround I just defined my Debug build to also use the Development Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your developer certificate installed on the machine, AND that your private key installed with it. You can check this in the Keychain Access tool in your Utilities folder. The cert should expand to a private key icon with your name on it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the "keychain" into which you installed your certificate is not currently set as your "default keychain".  I had the same (or very similar problems) when my default keychain was somehow switched to a different default.

Open Keychain Access (Applications -> Utilities -> Keychain Access)

On the top left list box called "Keychains" make sure the keychain into which you installed your developer certificate (usually "login") is still bold (ie: set to the default keychain).

You can set the default keychain by right (or control) clicking on the keychain you want ("login" for example) and selecting the "Make Keychain 'xxx' Default".

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Xcode 4.0 on SL.

In the Organizer window, doing a "drag and drop" of the provisioning profile always gives a "Valid signing identity not found".

You have to use the + (add) icon and search for your provisioning profile file to upload it on your device. It just worked for me (no need to reinstall all the stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all expired provisioning profiles in Xcode organizer did the trick for me. After this I clicked on the *Refresh* button in the organizer and the provisioning profiles have been downloaded automatically.